# ListView get second column value

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to retrieve the second column value of a `ListView`:

```
void PrintText(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    object item = listBox1.SelectedItem;

    if (item == null) {
    txtSelectedItem.Text = "No item currently selected.";
} else {
    txtSelectedItem.Text = item.ToString();
}
```

The above will return both columns as one string, however I only want the second column.

Here is my XAML:

```
  <ListView x:Name="lvSurname" ItemsSource="{Binding User}"        
      SelectionChanged="lvSurname_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         GridViewColumn Header="Surname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Surname}" />
         GridViewColumn Header="ClientID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ClientID}" />
      </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And my `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: txt.SelectedItem.Text = (item as User).ClientId; ?

Comment: This gives error: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred..... Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
txtSelectedItem.Text = ((User)listBox1.SelectedItem).ClientID;
```

Comment: Error: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0' 2 [System.String.System.String] to type 'User'.

Comment: @Davomate You need to tell the truth about what you populated the ListView with. Show how you populated it. Show the code.

Comment: It is loaded from an Access database
.. cut down code ..

     while (reader.Read())
     {
      lvSurname.Items.Add(new { Surname=reader["PSurname"].ToString(), ClientID=reader["PClientID"].ToString());
       }

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't format the code right: Its basically loaded from OleDbRatareader as a reader loop: then its adds each item:                      lvSurname.Items.Add( new { Surname=reader.["PSurname"].ToString, ClientID=reader["PClientID"].ToString() );

Comment: new User {Surname = whatever }... Why define a class user if you plan to use annonymous types.

Comment: How do I make the types not anonymous?

Comment: I think I need to load the rows into an IList, then bind the list to the listview.

Comment: @Davomate, to make the types not anonymous, just code it like @Milan has suggested, `lvSurname.Items.Add(new User { Surname = ...`. Essentially you just include the word `User` to make the addition an object of that type. It's similar to saying `User u  = new User { Surname = ... }; lvSurname.Items.Add(u)`;

Comment: Thanks very much Milan and Chris Mack. It works a treat. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as correct (if the code I posted is working). Merry Christmas!